# Can we get a Twitter Bootstrap tag?

Tags: support, tags

Can you add a Twitter Bootstrap tag?

[bootstrap](https://drupal.org/project/bootstrap)

Comment: Can you provide some examples of questions where this would be appropriate?

Comment: There are quite a few questions relating to bootstrap if you do a search. It would just be better(for me atleat) to categorize them by bootstrap.

Comment: To be honest, since you are making the proposal, you should really provide some backup evidence as to why it would benefit the site.  It is the way the SE sites work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Bootstrap framework is no longer associated with Twitter so tightly as it used to be, it's no longer called "Twitter Bootstrap" in their own documentation, so including *twitter* in tag seems pointless. On SO it is used only for consistency with twitter-bootstrap-2 tag.

For the need of the tag itself, I do not think it's needed:

1. Questions that are really Bootstrap specific will be PHP / JS / CSS question that should rather be asked [on Stack Overflow, with tag that already exists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/twitter-bootstrap-3)
2. Questions vitally about Drupal part of the job will hardly ever (if at all) be specific to Bootstrap Framework, so [theming](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/theming) should be enough for them.
3. I can't imagine Drupal Answers user willing to answer only Bootstrap question, or specifically ignore them. Reason: Point 2. So usefulness of this tag for filtering is dubious.

Answer (score 1):

Counter-argument.

I could potentially see the usefulness of a tag for <strike>Twitter</strike> Bootstap in a Drupal environment.

There is a [base theme](https://drupal.org/project/bootstrap), and I can some potential questions about getting the proper classes into the right place, and possible some other things related to the base theme (but *not* general Bootstrap questions).

However, I would want to see enough questions to warrant the new tag.

I would also want to really think about what to call the tag.  I don't think **bootstrap** is a good tag, as it is too close to [bootstrapping](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/bootstrapping), which has a decent number of questions and IMHO is a more important tag for understanding Drupal.

Comment: There is some truth in your words (+1 from me). I will not fight this tag. I just wanted to express why I don't think it's needed, but if others thinks it is useful, well, I see no real harm in it. Maybe one - it would make it easier to omit [tag:theming] making some questions harder to find. But we can always retag.